# Audit or log Web Part closed or Web Part Deleted event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

We have a small SharePoint intranet web site with some contributors. Someone or may be automatically, one web part on SharePoint's list form page (Dispform.aspx) is getting closed.

Even if we open it, it gets closed automatically or by someone after couple of days.

Is it possible to log this event or is there any way to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the web part's 'Allow Close', 'Allow Delete', etc.? If not, set these to false and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I am trying out that currently. There is no "Allow Delete" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a new webpart page, add the List View, and rename it to DispForm.aspx (make sure you keep the old copy, rename the old file to something like oldDispForm.aspx). Use SP Designer to move the file to the same spot as the aspx pages under the List. In a few days, check to see if the old DispForm.aspx ListView closed.

In addition, I'd track down all the "Web Designers" that have access to edit the page.